# Panning is not working properly with scatter plots

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to use the functionality of panning on this scatter plot but its not at all smooth.Zoom works fine though.
I don't know tips and tricks for D3 so please help me with this.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 15]).on("zoom", zoom))
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("dataset.csv", function (data) {
    // Coerce the strings to numbers.
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.word = d.word
        d.xcord = +d.xcord;
        d.ycord = +d.ycord;
        //console.log(d.word);
    });

    // Compute the scales’ domains.
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.xcord; })).nice();
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.ycord; })).nice();

    // Add the points!
    svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(data)
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       //.attr("fill","grey")
       .attr("cx", function (d) {
           return x(d.xcord);
       })
       .attr("cy", function (d) {
           return y(d.ycord);
       })

       .attr("r", 1);

});

function zoom() {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Comment: For future posts I recommend you provide the data in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not utilizing a group element to create a *layer* to transition.  As you'll see in your code, it is necessary to first bind the transition object to the svg *layer*, and then give the svg *layer* yet another *layer* (a  element in this instance) to work with.

Use your D.O.M. inspector to view the children of the svg layer that you've appended.

You'll see that before you pan, the translation values of the g object are the default property values (translate(0,0).

[image]

After you pan the translation attributes will be different.

[image: Heading]

Essentially what is happening is that the g layer is being used as the main layer to append items to.  The svg layer in turn is acting as sort of a mask/window to view the translated g layer.  This approach will also work with svg elements in exchange for g elements.

Here is a jsfiddle for the corresponding code below: http://jsfiddle.net/blakedietz/seU2y/

Please note that I had to make quite a few modifications to get your code to work.  For future reference if you want someone to answer your question more swiftly I would advise that you create some sort of working example of your code.  Toy examples with fake data are often the best way to convey your problem at hand without causing the reader to do too much guess work to figure out what it is that you're trying to communicate.

```
// ********* START MY CODE

var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var margin = {top:0, right:0,bottom:0,left:0};

var data = d3.range(1,20).map(function(datum)
                          {

                              var coordinates = {};
                              coordinates.xcord   = datum;
                              coordinates.ycord   = datum;
                              return coordinates;
                          });

var xDomain = d3.extent(data.map(function(datum){ return datum.xcord}));
var yDomain = d3.extent(data.map(function(datum){ return datum.ycord}));

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain(xDomain).range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain(yDomain).range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

function zoom()
{
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale +                 ")");
}
// ********* END MY CODE 


// ********* START YOUR CODE
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().x(x).y(y).scaleExtent([1, 15]).on("zoom", zoom))
// MY MODIFICATION Adds g layer to append to.
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Compute the scales’ domains.
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.xcord; })).nice();
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.ycord; })).nice();

// Add the points!
svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
   //.attr("fill","grey")
   .attr("cx", function (d) {
       return x(d.xcord);
   })
   .attr("cy", function (d) {
       return y(d.ycord);
   })

   .attr("r", 1);
```

Comment: Just an extra clarification to arete's comments:  The top-level `<svg>` element doesn't respond to transforms in the same way as it's child elements.  They are interpretted as CSS/HTML transforms.  Since webkit browsers don't yet interpret standard CSS transform syntax, that means nothing will happen in them.  On Firefox, you'll get some change but they will also change the scale and position of the background, which throws off d3's calculations of the mouse position, resulting in jumpiness.  Always use a `<g>` for transforms.

Comment: P.S. I wrote a [long discussion on d3 zooming](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21356139/3128209)  for another user; it might be useful.

Comment: I really appreciate the write up.