# combining force-layout, semantic zoom, collapsable nodes, and sticky behaviour

Tags: d3.js, svg, zooming, force-layout

I found this, which goes into a great level of detail about semantic zoom, force-layout graphs and such:

[semantic zooming of force directed graph in d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344340/sematic-zooming-of-force-directed-graph-in-d3)

What I'm next trying to do is combine it with a few things, like:

- an optional background grid (don't ask, sigh);
- sticky node behaviour (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558);
- collapsible nodes.

I'd provide links, but apparently I need 10 reputation to post >2 links. Sigh.

I've started with the sticky node example. If I just flip on the fixed attribute, clicking/dragging doesn't work. So I'm sure it's because I haven't quite grasped what's going on with dragging when we're doing it all via the zoom module and display coordinate translation.

I really appreciate any and all help!

Thanks!

-adrian

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly the same by the sounds of it. Currently have a force graph with semantic zooming, panning, dragging nodes (albeit bugging dragging). Collapsable nodes would be a really cool feature to add and im trying to decide on whether to have mouse over behaviour as shown here - http://jsfiddle.net/blt909/aVhd8/20/ or to use the fisheye lens as shown here - https://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/ . How far did you get with yours? im struggling to find examples to help me.